# How to avoid name collision in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I'm learning by reading Maxima manual.

Maxima has many built-in functions and global variables.
I worry about the possibility of overwriting the same name function or variable which already exists.

Is there a convenient way to avoid the name collision in Maxima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about namespaces, - no, I've never heard of namespaces in Maxima.

- the easiest way to solve your problem is to write prefixes to user-defined variables and functions
- another option is to check if function\variable already exists via `describe(FUNCTIONNAME)`. If it prints text, than function is predefined =)

Code example:

```
a:1;
b:2;
map:3;
map(describe, values);

(%o25) 1
(%o26) 2
(%o27) 3
No exact match found for topic a.
  Try ?? a (inexact match) instead.
  No exact match found for topic b.
  Try ?? b (inexact match) instead.
 Function: map (<f>, <expr_1>, ..., <expr_n>)
     Returns an expression whose leading operator is the same as that
     ....
     ....
  There are also some inexact matches for map.
  Try ?? map to see them.
(%o28) [false,false,true]
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. That would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimantal package by [Robert Dodier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871096/robert-dodier)

http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/contrib/namespaces

```
(%i1) load("namespaces")$
(%i2) in_namespace(foo);
(%o2)                          #<PACKAGE "$FOO">
(%i3) z: 42;
(%o3)                                 42
(%i4) in_namespace(maxima)$

(%i5) z;
(%o5)                                  z
(%i6) foo|z;
(%o6)                                 42
```